# SpringBoot Compile-time Request Mapping Annotation Check

Tags: spring-boot, compilation, annotations

Is there any mechanism to check correctness of applying request mapping annotations?

I mean `@RequestMapping`, `@GetMapping` e.t.c.

For example: I would like to get compilation error on following method declaration due to wrong parameter binding:

```
@GetMapping("/ololo/{myParam}")
public Boolean isAccountExists(String myParameter) {
    return true;
}
```